# How to Load or Maintain State of Fragment in RecyclerView

Tags: android, youtube, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have already integrated and loaded fragments in recyclerview. I am playing with YoutubePlayerFragment. My only question is how to handle **state** of **youtube player** or **youtubePlayerFragment** in recycerview ?

Any help appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: Fragments inside of RecyclerViews are a really bad idea.  The fragment lifecycle doesn't work well with recycling.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @GabeSechan . I have multiple youtube video ids and play those in youtube player. Can suggest what is best option to achieve it ?